# Android project with multiple packages import R. file

Tags: android, import

Background: Big project with multiple packages. Resources need to be shared among packages

I saw another developer importing the `R` file of classes in other packages and that compiles. However, I'm not sure of `R` being imported. Through my experience if I import `R` by accident, I'll only see compile errors.

Can any one seeing the dilemma here help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no issues in importing `R`; unless everything is in the same package you *must* import it.

I have no projects that don't have `most` classes importing `R`. "Accidentally" importing it shouldn't cause errors, either; at worst it should unnecessary.

Comment: Could you explain a little more? I had problems before import com.package.name.R and throws me "R cannot be resolved to a variable".

Comment: @EmbraceTheSea Then something was likely wrong; `R` is a class like any other, and should be importable at will. Without knowing more, I'd say that the project's dependencies were configured incorrectly, and the compiled `R` wasn't on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by packages : are these java packages?
If the R files package is different from the Class file where you are trying to use its assets, Eclipse will import the R class.

Comment: yes, packages of source code. not resources or any other files